# CSS Target Last Paragraph After Heading

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've been looking how to edit the last paragraph after a heading using CSS.

I thought `#div h1 ~ p:last-child` would do the trick, but it skips down past the second heading and edits the last paragraph before the list. I've been searching for awhile and came across a few advanced css help sites, but they're repeating themselves with the most common advanced selectors.

The HTML:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>

<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>content</p>
<ul>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#contentContainer > h1 ~ p:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: The problem you'll face, with this mark-up, is that you can't yet (so far as I know) select the last element before another sibling (since that would require selecting an element based on other elements that follow).

Comment: Okay, then I likely need to go to jQuery to target it, right?

Comment: Not necessarily jQuery, but JavaScript, I'm afraid, yes.

Comment: Ah well, I was hoping not to, but I'm not entirely in opposition of it. Thank you.

Comment: Well, [one](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jrfXa/) or [two](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jrfXa/1/) non-jQuery approaches you could take.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tilde character represents the general sibling selector:

> The general sibling combinator selector is very similar to the
>   adjacent sibling combinator selector The difference is that that the
>   element being selected doesn't need immediately succeed the first
>   element, but can appear anywhere after it.

This means it it could be after 100 different tags (e.g. h2, h3, div, img etc) and the css will still affect that.

As far as I am aware, there is no selector, or combination of selectors that will be able to do what you are trying to do, as the elements are all on the same level, and CSS doesn't get as advanced as "do this before it hits a different element".

Sorry - if I am wrong, which I hope I am for your sake.

Comment: Nope, you're right. It doesn't seem to be possible with the as-current (Aug 2012) Selectors 4 draft either. Maybe when it's more clearly defined, as there are lots of ambiguities in the spec right now...

Comment: @BoltClock - music to my ears when someone says I'm right ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to create a space between heading and last paragraph you can use

```
p + h2, p + h3 { 
    padding-top: 20px 
}
```